# How do you stratify a Poisson regression in GLM?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, poisson-regression

I would like to obtain a stratified baseline hazard in a Poisson regression model.
What is the correct way to do it ?

Let *A* (=0/1) be the binary covariate on which I wish to stratify my baseline hazard, is it sufficient to write (in lme4, for example) :

```
glmer(event ~ interval*A + (1 + A|C), data=data,family=poisson,
                offset=log(time))
```

In this case, I got an estimate for a fixed coefficient for A0, but that does not interest me.
It suggests to me that something is wrong with my formulation.

Any help ?

Thanks :-)

Comment: If i'm understanding this correctly, you want to remove the main effect of your variable $A$. You can simply add $-A$ in your formula or write $\text{intercept}:A$ if you just want the interaction. The notation $A * B$ is equivalent to $A + B + A:B$ in R.

Comment: It's exact, I want to remove the main effect of my variable $A$. I tried to add $-A$ in the formula but it did not change anything. As well as writing $ interval:A$ which gave me only the estimation in one level of A.

Comment: If $A$ is truly zero-one valued, have you included it as a factor? Also add $0$ in the glm formula to prevent overparametrization.

Comment: $A$ is not included as a fixed factor in the model. It is used as an interaction term with a factor C. When I add $0$ and $-A$ in the model the estimated coefficient are the same than with `interval*A + (1 + A|C)` but the labels of two coefficients have changed !  `(Intercept)  -7.82887`   in `interval0  -7.668470`  and `A0 
 -0.59597` in `interval0:A  -0.598916`